# iOS: CHCSVParser & NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, nsarray, nspredicate

I'm currently attempting to use CHCSVParser to parse through a CSV file containing over 1500 entries, and 8 rows. I've successfully managed to parse through the file, and what I get is an NSArray of NSArrays of NSStrings.

For example here's what I get:

```
Loading CSV from: (
        (
        Last,
        First,
        Middle,
        Nickname,
        Gender,
        City,
        Age,
        Email
    ),
        (
        Doe,
        John,
        Awesome,
        "JD",
        M,
        "San Francisco",
        "20",
        "john@john.doe"
    ),
```

How could I sort this into a Person object and filter through it using NSPredicate, like Mattt Thompson does [here](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/).

Here's how I initialize the parser:

```
//Prepare Roster
    NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType: @"csv"];
    NSArray *myFile = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfCSVFile:pathToFile options:CHCSVParserOptionsSanitizesFields];
    NSLog(@"Loading CSV from: %@", myFile);
```

Here's what Mattt does in the article I linked, which I'd like to do with my code:

```
NSArray *firstNames = @[ @"Alice", @"Bob", @"Charlie", @"Quentin" ];
NSArray *lastNames = @[ @"Smith", @"Jones", @"Smith", @"Alberts" ];
NSArray *ages = @[ @24, @27, @33, @31 ];

NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
[firstNames enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
    person.firstName = firstNames[idx];
    person.lastName = lastNames[idx];
    person.age = ages[idx];
    [people addObject:person];
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a suitable `Person` class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
// ...
@property(nonatomic) int age;
// ...
@end
```

Then you can read your data into an array of `Person` objects by enumerating the
`myFile` array. Inside the block, `row` is the "sub-array" for a single row:

```
NSMutableArray *people = [NSMutableArray array];
[myFile enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSArray *row, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (row > 0) { // Skip row # 0 (the header)
       Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
       person.lastName = row[0];
       person.firstName = row[1];
       // ...
       person.age = [row[6] intValue];
       // ...
       [people addObject:person];
   }
}];
```

Now you can filter that array as shown in the tutorial:

```
NSPredicate *smithPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName = %@", @"Smith"];
NSArray *filtered = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:smithPredicate];
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining and simplifying the process!